# An element in the middle of a line

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, pgfkeys, tikz-node

Please consider my minimal example. I would like to place an additional element -in this case a text field- in the middle of the line between nodes A and B. How does this work?

Which of the following commands would be the correct one here?

1. `append after command={...}`,
2. `node contens={...}`,
3. `code={...}` or `path picture={...}`

Minimalbeispiel:

```
 \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, fit, shadings, shadows, shapes.arrows, arrows.meta, matrix, mindmap}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        textfield extension/.style ={
            rounded corners, 
            arrows={-Straight Barb[angle=60:9pt 3]},
            append after command={
                node[circle, fill=red] {\TextField[name=1,width=3cm,height=1em,multiline=false,bordercolor=black, charsize=9pt]{}}
            }
        }]
        \node(A) [circle, fill=red] at (0,0){A};
        \node(B) [circle, fill=red] at (10,0){B};
        \draw[solid, black, textfield extension] (A) -- (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the `insert path` option together with the `calc` library, but it would be semantically better to use a `to node`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    textfield extension/.style args={#1 and #2}{
        rounded corners, 
        arrows={-Straight Barb[angle=60:9pt 3]},
        insert path={
            node[circle, fill=red] at ($(#1)!.5!(#2)$) {\TextField[name=1,width=3cm,height=1em,multiline=false,bordercolor=black, charsize=9pt]{}}
        }
    }]
    \node(A) [circle, fill=red] at (0,0){A};
    \node(B) [circle, fill=red] at (10,0){B};
    \draw[solid, black, textfield extension={A and B}] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    extension line/.style={
        rounded corners, 
        arrows={-Straight Barb[angle=60:9pt 3]},
    }]
    \node(A) [circle, fill=red] at (0,0){A};
    \node(B) [circle, fill=red] at (10,0){B};
    \draw[solid, black, extension line] 
        (A) -- 
        node[midway, circle, fill=red]  {\TextField[name=1,width=3cm,height=1em,multiline=false,bordercolor=black, charsize=9pt]{}} 
        (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly your problem. To me is unclear, why you need `textfield extension`. Just inserting a text in node at middle of the arrow between nodes A and B is not needed.

To my opinion the simplest way doing what you say in question title is:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    C/.style = {circle, fill=red, minimum size=\nodewidth,
                append after command = {
                    node[draw, semithick, fill=white, font=\small,
                         minimum width=\nodewidth-8pt] {#1}
                                        }
                }
                    ]
\def\nodewidth{22mm}
\node (A) [circle, fill=red]            {A};
\node (B) [circle, fill=red] at (10,0)  {B};
\draw[-{Straight Barb[angle=60:9pt 3]}, semithick]
        (A) --  node[C=text] {} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I misunderstood your question than please edit it and more clear explain what is your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a normal node command:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, fit, shadings, shadows, shapes.arrows, arrows.meta, matrix, mindmap}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \begin{document}
    \Form
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        textfield extension/.style ={
            rounded corners,
            arrows={-Straight Barb[angle=60:9pt 3]},
        }]
        \node(A) [circle, fill=red] at (0,0){A};
        \node(B) [circle, fill=red] at (10,0){B};
        \draw[solid, black, textfield extension] (A) -- (B);
        \node[circle,fill=red,above] at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$) {\TextField[name=1,width=3cm,height=1em,multiline=false,bordercolor=black, charsize=9pt]{}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't place a node automatically along a `--` path. This only works by writing the `node` in the path directly.

There's `insert path` but you can't use this anywhere and especially not after `--`:

```
\tikz\draw (0,0) -- (2,1) [insert path={node[midway]{a}}];
```

If you want to place nodes via a style, you'll need either the `to` or the `edge` path operator. Then you can set nodes along that path with `edge node`. (The [`quotes`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#pgf.quotes) extends that functionality for easier input.)

To make the following examples shorter, I've defined:

```
\tikzset{
  every textfield extension/.style={
    rounded corners, arrows={-Straight Barb[angle=60:9pt 3]}},
  my edge node/.style={
    edge node={node[midway,circle,fill=red]{
        \TextField[name=1,width=3cm,height=1em,multiline=false,bordercolor=black, charsize=9pt]{}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The definition of `textfield extension` then is dependent on how you want to use the style.

If you want to use `to` and a `\path[textfield extension]` declaration you'll want to append that edge node to `every to`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  textfield extension/.style={every textfield extension, every to/.append style=my edge node}]
\node(A) [circle, fill=red] at (0,0){A};
\node(B) [circle, fill=red] at (10,0){B};
\draw[solid, black, textfield extension] (A) to (B) to[bend left=90] (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

For `edge` and a `\path[textfield extension]` declaration you'll want to append that edge node to `every edge`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  textfield extension/.style={every textfield extension,every edge/.append style=my edge node}]
\node(A) [circle, fill=red] at (0,0){A};
\node(B) [circle, fill=red] at (10,0){B};
\path[solid, black, textfield extension] (A) edge (B)
                                         (B) edge[bend left=90] (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Both these solutions place the nodes along both `to`s/`edge`s while `to` treats both connections as one path and only places one arrow head and `edge` constructs two separate paths, thus two arrow heads.

However, since this looks like a style that's only to be used with connection between nodes, i.e. `edge`s, I'll use it this way:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  textfield extension/.style={every textfield extension, my edge node}]
\node(A) [circle, fill=red] at (0,0){A};
\node(B) [circle, fill=red] at (10,0){B};
\path[solid, black] (A) edge[textfield extension] (B)
                    (B) edge[bend left=90] (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If you still want this style to be applied to multiple edges on one path, I'll suggest defining `edges/.style={every edge/.append style={#1}}` and then:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  edges/.style={every edge/.append style={#1}},
  textfield extension/.style={every textfield extension, my edge node}]
\node(A) [circle, fill=red] at (0,0){A};
\node(B) [circle, fill=red] at (10,0){B};
\node(C) [circle, fill=red] at (0,10){C};
\path[solid, black, edges=textfield extension] (A) edge (B)
                                                   edge (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I've also added a `insert path` solution, I don't know if that is a better user interface, though.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\tikzset{
  every textfield extension/.style={
    rounded corners, arrows={-Straight Barb[angle=60:9pt 3]}},
  my edge node/.style={
    edge node={node[midway,circle,fill=red]{
        \TextField[name=1,width=3cm,height=1em,multiline=false,bordercolor=black, charsize=9pt]{}
      }
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  textfield extension/.style={every textfield extension, every to/.append style=my edge node}]
\node(A) [circle, fill=red] at (0,0){A};
\node(B) [circle, fill=red] at (10,0){B};
\draw[solid, black, textfield extension] (A) to (B) to[bend left=90] (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  textfield extension/.style={every textfield extension, every edge/.append style=my edge node}]
\node(A) [circle, fill=red] at (0,0){A};
\node(B) [circle, fill=red] at (10,0){B};
\path[solid, black, textfield extension] (A) edge (B)
                                         (B) edge[bend left=90] (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  textfield extension/.style={every textfield extension, my edge node}]
\node(A) [circle, fill=red] at (0,0){A};
\node(B) [circle, fill=red] at (10,0){B};
\path[solid, black] (A) edge[textfield extension] (B)
                    (B) edge[bend left=90] (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  edges/.style={every edge/.append style={#1}},
  textfield extension/.style={every textfield extension, my edge node}]
\node(A) [circle, fill=red] at (0,0){A};
\node(B) [circle, fill=red] at (10,0){B};
\node(C) [circle, fill=red] at (0,10){C};
\path[solid, black, edges=textfield extension] (A) edge (B)
                                                   edge (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  textfield extension path/.style args={#1to#2}{
    insert path={#1 edge[textfield extension] #2}},
  edges/.style={every edge/.append style={#1}},
  textfield extension/.style={every textfield extension, my edge node}]
\node(A) [circle, fill=red] at (0,0){A};
\node(B) [circle, fill=red] at (10,0){B};
\node(C) [circle, fill=red] at (0,10){C};
\path[solid, black] [textfield extension path=(A) to (B), textfield extension path=(C) to (B)];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```